# Indexing columns in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, indexing, subquery

With some help I have recently created a query using 2 local tables; one of the tables being for 'Sales', and the other being 'Daily Prices'. Our sales table is currently unable to store the price which the product was sold at on the day, so we bring that price in from the 'Daily Prices' table by matching up the Product ID as well as the date fields in both tables. The daily prices table is literally just 3 fields (Product ID, Date, Price) appended to a master table each day (about 50k new lines per day). The query had to take into account the fact that the 'Daily Prices' table is only generated on week days, and that there would be sales on the weekend. To do so, the logic brings the price in from the **first available date after the sales date** (e.g. a sale made on a Friday or a Saturday would be reported on using the price generated on the Monday)

The code I have used seems to work when I use a small sample data set, however takes forever with larger ones. Below is the code I am using:

```
SELECT ProdID,
        Date,
        (SELECT Price
        FROM   PRICE_TABLE P
        WHERE  P.ProdID = S.ProdID
        AND    P.Date = (SELECT MIN(P2.Date)
                         FROM   PRICE_TABLE P2
                         WHERE  P2.ProdId = P.ProdID
                         AND    P2.Date >= S.Date))
FROM   SALES_HISTORY S;
```

My question is, how would I go about speeding this up? Would indexing these fields improve the speed? I have never indexed fields before so would need a bit of help in doing so.

Thank you!

Comment: "about 50k [...] lines", "Would indexing [...] improve the speed" - Yes, most likely it will. You'll definitely want an index on `PRICE_TABLE(ProdId)`, or maybe on `PRICE_TABLE(ProdId,Date)`.

Comment: You could also try using `GROUP BY` instead, like `SELECT h.ProdID, h.Date, MAX( p.Price ) FROM SALES_HISTORY h INNER JOIN PRICE_TABLE p ON h.ProdID = p.ProdID AND h.Date <= p.Date GROUP BY h.ProdId, h.Date HAVING p.Date = MIN( p.Date )`. (Not sure if this works with Access though.)

Comment: Just try it out, on a copy of your database if you want to be careful. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce

Comment: I will try your method too, I managed to successfully index the tables which made the speed 1000x faster... Useful to have two sets of code though! thanks for your help

Comment: Since the subqueries must execute for each row of SALES_HISTORY, performance will always be slow. Some index changes may help, but I wouldn't count on any major improvement. Remember also that if you have relationships between the tables, Access creates indexes on those fields behind the scenes. I can think of 2 other options. Add the price to the SALES_HISTORY table or generate 'Daily Price' records for the missing days.